# Linux serial console disconnect to trigger user logout

Tags: command-line, login

I am trying to force a user-logout from console (physical serial console, or `virsh console` in case of KVM) on disconnect. I.e., when user is on console, logged in and then disconnects without logging off, on re-connecting, user must re-login. How to achieve this ?

P.S. I have explored `bash` session timeout - `export TMOUT`, but that is not what I want.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* last year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Comment: You didn't specifically mention a OS/release, but you've tagged a release that is EOSS (*for some architectures; EOL for others*).

Comment: Sorry the issue is not limited-to bionic ! I removed the tag, this is a general issue which I want to solve for all/any ubuntu releases that I use.

Comment: @ani but you will end up with an answer that works for 22.04/23.10 and maybe not suited for 18.04. A lot changed between 18.04 and 22.04.

Comment: @Rinzwind, I am fine with that! I can try a solution on Jammy alone, but at the least I will understand the _approach_ and if there is any generic solution that is welcome

Comment: @Ani Are you sure the other end is properly sending `tcsendbreak` on disconnect?

Comment: @DanielT I assume it does!